# Static initializer runs after the constructor, why?

Tags: java, constructor, static-initialization

I have 2 classes:

Class A:

```
public class A {
    static B b = new B();

     static {
         System.out.println("A static block");
     }

     public A() {
         System.out.println("A constructor");
     }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B {
     static {
         System.out.println("B static block");
         new A();
     }

     public B() {
         System.out.println("B constructor");
     }
}
```

I create a Main class which just creates new A:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A();
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
B static block
A constructor
B constructor
A static block
A constructor
```

As you can see, the constructor of A is invoked before its static initializer.

I understand it got something to do with the cyclic dependency I created but I was under the impression the static initializer should always run before the constructor.

**What is the reason for this to happen (technically in the java implementation) ?**

**Is it recommended to avoid static initializers all together ?**

Comment: Whoever downvoted please leave a comment

Comment: good question actually +1 .. :)

Comment: @AviramSegal some people are habitual of downvote ..they never read the whole question, by reading the heading, they downvote the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
static B b = new B();
```

is before

```
static {
     System.out.println("A static block");
}
```

So you require that the B instance be initialized before you print `"A static block"`.

And initializing the B class means you need to create a A instance. So there's no way for "A static block" to be printed before the A instance is constructed.

Yes, the static initialization of A is **launched** before the constructor is launched but, apart deadlocking, there would be no other solution to the sequence you require.

Note the warning in [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) :

> Because the Java programming language is multithreaded, initialization
>   of a class or interface requires careful synchronization, since some
>   other thread may be trying to initialize the same class or interface
>   at the same time. **There is also the possibility that initialization of
>   a class or interface may be requested recursively as part of the
>   initialization of that class or interface; for example, a variable
>   initializer in class A might invoke a method of an unrelated class B,
>   which might in turn invoke a method of class A.** The implementation of
>   the Java virtual machine is responsible for taking care of
>   synchronization and recursive initialization by using the following
>   procedure [the doc goes on with the complete procedure]

A best practice, in Java as in other languages, is basically to avoid cyclic dependencies as their resolution may be very hard to predict.

Comment: I would understand an error, but why allow that inconsistent behavior ? also, couldn't find documentation for that

Comment: Cant really get "So there's no way for "A static block" to be printed before the A instance is constructed." [This](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-static-class-block-methods-variables/) and [this](http://www.topperskills.com/tutorials/java/java-static-block-example.html) says  "it gets executed when the class is loaded in the memory. " Isnt class loaded before creating instance? If yes, shouldnt static block be executed before creating instance? In other words, why the output is not "B static block, A static block, A constructor, B constructor, A constructor"?